# How to pass function variable parameter to angular 2 http subscribe callbacks?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have tried

```
this.propositionService.addProposition(this.proposition)
                       .subscribe(this.addSuccessCallback, this.addFailureCallback);
```

The problem I am facing is the both `addSuccessCallback` and `addFailureCallback` can't access **this** object. I don't want to use embedded lambda expressions. it makes code less cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

You can [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) component's `this` context to the callbacks as following:

```
this.propositionService.addProposition(this.proposition)
        .subscribe(this.addSuccessCallback.bind(this), this.addFailureCallback.bind(this));
```

Comment: works like a charm. I am just wondering if it doesn't affect performance !!